# Looping Table Rows in Form

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I'm trying to code a form that sits inside a table that has only one row. The row contains a drop down box, text box and a checkbox.

```
<table class="table text-size-12">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Location</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-nowrap">COD Charge</th>
                <th scope="col">Allow Negotiate</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                for($rows = 0; $rows < 5; $rows++):
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="location" class="form-control" style="width:250px">
                            <option value="">--- Select Location ---</option>
                            <?php foreach ($locations as $state): ?>
                                <optgroup label="--- <?= $state->name ?> ---">
                                    <?php foreach ($state->locations as $area): ?>
                                        <option value="{{ $key }}"><?= $area->name ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach ?>
                                </optgroup>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="shipping_fee_value">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="shipping_fee_allow_negotiate">
                        <script>
                            document.getElementById('shipping_fee_allow_negotiate').onchange = function (){
                                document.getElementById('shipping_fee_value').disabled = this.checked;
                            }
                        </script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endfor ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

As you can see, I've used Javascript so that if the checkbox is checked, the text box will be disabled.

```
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="shipping_fee_value">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="shipping_fee_allow_negotiate">
                        <script>
                            document.getElementById('shipping_fee_allow_negotiate').onchange = function (){
                                document.getElementById('shipping_fee_value').disabled = this.checked;
                            }
                        </script>
                    </td>
```

And I've also looped the rows 5 times using `for`. My problem is, the checkbox disabling text box script only works in the first row, how do I allow each row to be independent?

P.S. I prefer not hard coding every specific row just because so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeating the id of the elements. You can't do this. id are meant to be unique. Set a unique id on the every element.

```
<td>
    <input type="text" id="shipping_fee_value_<?= $rows ?>">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="shipping_fee_allow_negotiate" data-target="shipping_fee_value_<?= $rows ?>">
    <script>
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('shipping_fee_allow_negotiate');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].onchange = function() {
                document.getElementById(this.dataset.target).disabled = this.checked;
            }
        }
    </script>
</td>
```

Here we are using the `$row` variable to add a index to the `id` property on the input.

```
<input type="text" id="shipping_fee_value_0"/>
```

Also we use the `data-target` property on the checkbox to tell him  which specific input to handle on the `onchange` callback.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="shipping_fee_allow_negotiate" data-target="shipping_fee_value_0">
```

And finally the selector to assign the callback is using getElementsByClassName to select all the checkboxes.

Comment: I realize that, but I can't think of a way to make the id unique. I've haven't been coding html and php for 2 years now and I've gotten so rusty. Just needed some input from other people.

Comment: Are you implying that `$row` is different from `$rows` declared in the `for` condition? Because for some reason the code doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry! It should be `$rows`. fixed. $rows changes the value in every step of the loop. Its 0, 1, 2, 3.... so it adds a unique part to the `id` property of the inputs

Comment: Triple checked that I did the exact same code as yours. Checking the checkbox doesn't disable the textbox at all.

Comment: Would appreciate if you could suggest me other tricks to look into to.

Comment: There was a mistake when assigning the callback. Its fixed and tested now. Callback needs to be assigned to every checkbox. That's the reason for the loop on the script. First get all checkboxes with specified class, then loop this array and assign the onchange callback to every element.

Comment: Nice! It works now! Thank you so much. One last question, If I were to send the input into a database, say a user inputs something in the text box, then checks the checkbox, (text box disabled after text is inputted), would it still post the value of the text box?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222053/discussion-between-gabriel-a-lopez-lopez-and-naim-fauzi).

Answer (score 1):

Because your id is common that's why they consider only the first row instead of common id use dynamic id.

Comment: May I know exactly or at least something to look into to make the id dynamic? Like do i code the id in php? I'm kinda lost here mate